# javascript split and match not working (Parse scalable search)

Tags: javascript, regex, parse-platform

I am trying to implement a scaleable search as per the [parse docs](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/).

Below is the code I am using which is pretty much lifted from the post.

```
var _ = require("underscore");

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Exercises", function (request, response) {
    var Exercise = request.object;

    console.log("Log1" + Exercise.get("exerciseName"));

    var toLowerCase = function (w) {
        return w.toLowerCase();
    };

    var words = Exercise.get("exerciseName").split(/b/);
    words = _.map(words, toLowerCase);

    console.log("Log 2" + words);

    var stopWords = ["the", "in", "and", "with", "on"]
    words = _.filter(words, function (w) {
        return w.match(/^w+$/) && !_.contains(stopWords, w);
    });

    console.log("Log 3" + words);

    var hashtags = Exercise.get("exerciseName").match(/#.+?b/g);
    hashtags = _.map(hashtags, toLowerCase);

    Exercise.set("words", words);
    Exercise.set("hashtags", hashtags);
    response.success();
});
```

Here is my output at each log.

Log 1: `Squats with Dumbells`

Log 2: `squats with dumbells`

Log 3:

It seems that following this line:

`words = _.filter(words, function(w) { return w.match(/^w+$/) && ! _.contains(stopWords, w); });`

Nothing is returned. in Log 2 i expected that I would be given `["squats", "with","dumbells"]`

My `Hashtags` variable is also empty, is there an issue with `match` in this code?

Comment: why do you need `w.match(/^w+$/)` inside the `_.filter` function? Simple `_.contains()` call does the trick

Comment: Can you give me an example? this is my first `_` attempt. 
I am finding that `Log 2` does not contain an array of separate words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Here is a workding JSFiddle with all log statements](http://jsfiddle.net/ewk368tn/)

---

You really don't need the RegEx inside the filter function. But if you really want to check that `w` is a word, then you were missing a `\` right before `w` in your RegEx. This works as expected:

```
var stopWords = ["the", "in", "and", "with", "on"];

words = _.filter(words, function(w) {
    return w.match(/^\w+$/) && ! _.contains(stopWords, w);
    //               ^ this one
});
console.log(words);    // [ "squats", "dumbells" ]
```

---

The reason your hashtags is empty is because you have no hashtags in `Exercise.get("exerciseName")`. Also, you already have all the words in `words` array. You could get all hashtags by simply checking if the first character is a `#`:

```
var hashtags = _.filter(words, function(word) {
    return word.indexOf("#") === 0;
});
```

Comment: Using this exact code I do not get anything out of the function:
`I2015-05-31T13:48:18.810Z]Log1 Supine Shoulder Circumduction With Medicine Ball

I2015-05-31T13:48:18.811Z]Log 2 supine shoulder circumduction with medicine ball

I2015-05-31T13:48:18.812Z]Log 3 
`

Comment: Also should `Log 2` not contain my string split up??

Comment: Following the `_.filter` `words` does not contain anything

Comment: check out the jsfiddle and let me know if there are things you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with this?

```
words = _.filter(words, function(w) {
   return w.match(/^w+$/) && ! _.contains(stopWords, w); 
});
```

Think about your regular expression. `/^w+$/` is testing for the string "w", repeated 1 or more times, from the beginning to the end of the string.  IE: it would match true for "wwww" or "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww", but not "squats" or "dumbells".

I assume you're meaning the `w` variable rather than the "w" string, but it looks like you are trying to `match` `w` against `w`... making the whole match essentially a `if (1 === 1)`.